# iptables to ip6tables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ip6tables

How do I turn my iptables rules to ip6tables rules?  I am getting a Bad Address:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ALLOW

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.255.255/24

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.5/24 -i eth0 -j DNAT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange! Please visit the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get more information on how to post to this site. To get to your question, please edit your post to include additional context please. What are your IPv6 addresses? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Those are IPv4 addresses. Use the equivalent IPv6 addresses.